# Trying to understand how to fit Backbone into this menu

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just learning Backbone-- it seems awesome but I'm still learning how exactly to wield it. I'm trying to figure out how it fits into this situation where I've been asked to use it, and I was hoping for some leads.

Basically we have a menu that's already totally made HTML/CSS wise, it's done. This menu lets a user select what color of product they're looking for (for example), then what *fabric*, and so on. The functionality they would like to add to this menu is that as soon as the first choice is made, the color, the second set of options should grey out accordingly: for instance, if you pick red and only 2 of the 5 fabrics are available in red, the other 3 should grey out.

They want this done with Backbone, and it's my first time putting this library to use.

So as soon as a color is picked, I guess I need to make an AJAX request and immediately find out what's good for fabrics and update accordingly, but I'm hitting a little wall because if the HTML is already done...then...there's no "view", not that I made anyway...so...help me out here. Am I thinking about it wrong? Can this be done anyway?

Comment: A backbone view can reference an existing element in the DOM, you can either specify the element when you declare your view `el:'#myMenu'` (or pass it in when you create an instance of it) or you can set it at a later point using the [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) method.

Comment: Ah! I knew that but didn't think of it. A solid starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd probably do is have a model to manage your options (color, fabric, etc.). Then, when one of the attributes changes, you `fetch` the updated possibilities from your server. Of course, for this to work, you need to define your model's `url` function to generate the url corresponding to you endpoint.

When the data returns from the server, you render the view into the form's element, which will replace the HTML already there (in effect updating what is displayed to the user).

Realistically, although your form already is written, you'll probably find it easier to generate the same HTML in your view's `render` function, and simply rerender the form each time an option changes. (I.e. don't have the form HTML already present.)

Another option would be to update the values, etc. in the existing form in the DOM using the view's `render` function.